# How do I fit an image into a div box with description?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box that contains both an image and description under the image. Currently, my image overflows the box. I also want to be able to create a row of these boxes. How do I fix this? Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/br136ofp/

HTML below:

```
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#"><img class="image" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></a>
      <br>Blah blah blah blah blah
      <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfssdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
      </div>
```

CSS below:

```
 div.img {
     margin: 5px;
     float: left;
     width: 180px;
 }

 img.image {
   max-width:400px;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your demo work, you need to set the image to `max-width: 100%` so it won't overflow the parent, and either put spaces in the text, or use `word-break: break-all` so the text won't overflow the parent.

```css
div.img {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
img.image {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <a href="#"><img class="image" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></a>
  <br>Blah blah blah blah blah
  <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfssdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
img.image {
   width:100%
 }
```

Comment: They should? Why?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.img {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></a>
  <p>sdfsd fsdfsdfss dfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdf sdfsdf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the DIV an inline-block and add `width: 100%;` to the image (not only `max-width`):

https://jsfiddle.net/yu3sqgp8/1/